# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.On VPN

Tags: rest, spring-boot, cors, vpn

Dears ,

I got a strange issue on My Spring Boot Rest Services & angular JS,
When VPN on, API throw 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' But Without VPN its working correctly .

```
@Configuration
```

public class CorsConfig {

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802102/spring-boot-security-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r/51802163

Comment: @sajib I have already added that bean and Its working perfectly in normal case,Only when VPN is On Its Not working.

Comment: implement Filter?

Comment: Spring CORS filter there .@sajib

Comment: add @CrossOrigin in  your controller class

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that browser is sending the **option** request to server to get the server permission for the request in the form response headers

so, you need to set the following headers in the response as follows

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestOrigin);

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", JWTConstants.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOWED_METHODS);

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", JWTConstants.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOWED_HEADERS);
```

or you can simply use * in place of request origin so that it will allow any request.

for more info about the topic plz refer

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Test_Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing_(OTG-CLIENT-007)

hope this helps you

Comment: I have Used Spring FIlter So where I have to Implement above code you mention @aditya

Comment: This code will be implemented in the spring filter itself when the browser will make the option request you need to set those headers