# Access blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: angular, spring, rest, spring-boot, http

I'm trying to create a user administration API for my web app. When I send an API call from my frontend to my backend, a cors error occurs. How can the cors problem be solved? I've read a lot of threads, but I haven't made any progress.

**Error after createUser() API call**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/create' 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

**Angular header.config.ts**

```
export const HTTP_OPTIONS = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
  })
};
```

**Angular rest-user.service.ts**

```
  public createUser() {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.USER_ENDPOINT + 'create', HTTP_OPTIONS);
  }
```

**SpringConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    @Override  
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().oauth2Client()
        .and().oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

**UserRestController.class**

```
@PostMapping("/user/create")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createUser(Principal principal) throws UserAlreadyExistsException {
    userServiceFacadeImpl.createUser(principal.getName());
}
```

**Network Message**

[image]

**UPDATE 20.06.19**

```
  private createUser() {

    const headersObject = new HttpHeaders();

    this.oktaAuth.getAccessToken().then( (value) => {

      headersObject.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + value);
      headersObject.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      const httpOptions = {
        headers: headersObject
      };

      this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/user/' + 'create', null, httpOptions);
    });

  }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add an origin to your CORS mapping. For example: `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");`.
See [https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_global_cors_configuration)

Comment: Thanks @youri, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 14):

You may need to config the CORS at Spring Boot side. Please add below class in your Project.

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {



    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

---

UPDATE:

To append Token to each request you can create one Interceptor as below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem('tokenKey'); // you probably want to store it in localStorage or something


    if (!token) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const req1 = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`),
    });

    return next.handle(req1);
  }

}
```

[Example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/26/angular-8-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example)

Comment: Have you replace SpringConfig class with above and please remove the header configuration on Angular and try again and let us know the outcome

Comment: I did, but I get this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Hello @laprof Make sure you have added Token to Header. Go to network tab and check the header There should be Authorization with your Token

Comment: I have added the token as shown above in the post update, but it does not appear in the header.

Comment: just a small change. also add 'Accept' in response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe"); to accept multipart request.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **Spring as Back-End server** and especially using **Spring Security** then i found a solution by putting `http.cors();` in the `configure` method. The method looks like that:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests() // authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // all requests are authenticated
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.cors();
}
```

Comment: Adding  **http.cors()** did the trick for me, thank you really much !

Comment: that ".httpBasic();" saved me from the 403 forbidden error i got stuck with in spring boot.thanks a lot :D

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER. Im using Springboot and Angular.

Answer (score 7):

Since the originating port 4200 is different than 8080,So before angular sends a create (PUT) request,it will send an OPTIONS request to the server to check what all methods and what all access-controls are in place. 
Server has to respond to that OPTIONS request with list of allowed methods and allowed origins.

Since you are using spring boot, the simple solution is to add `".allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");"`

In your spring config,class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

However a better approach will be to write a Filter(interceptor) which adds the necessary headers to each response.

Comment: Thanks. I added `.allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`, wrote a filter like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802102/spring-boot-security-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r) and delete the header options from angular. It still doesn't seem to work properly, I get the following error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 3):

CORS headers should be sent from the server. If you use PHP it will be like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-host');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: your-methods like POST,GET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type or other');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just create the required CORS configuration as a bean. As per the code below this will allow all requests coming from any origin.
This is good for development but insecure.  [Spring Docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

```
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular CLI on the frontend then

- Create a `proxy.conf.json` in your root directory and add the following

```
{

   "/api": {
     "target": "your backend url",
     "secure": true,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "pathRewrite": {
       "^/api": ""
     }
   }
 }
```

- Run your development server with this command `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
- You will access your backend in your code with the base url `${your frontend url}/api/`

Answer (score 1):

Tried almost every way through internet, but it was not working. Finally got the solution.
If injecting the CORS bean, add @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) to make sure, it is injected in spring config and not blocked by any other bean injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the http header at the http response of your resource. So it needs to be set serverside, you can remove the "HTTP_OPTIONS"-header from your angular HTTP-Post request.

Comment: When I remove the options from the Angular, another error occurs: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I tried to add a filter in spring like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802102/spring-boot-security-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to fix with the bellow in my php file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    // The request is using the POST method
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    return;

}
```

And there's no more complains!