# Blocked By CORS Policy Angular and Slim

Tags: angular, cors, slim, angular8

I am running angular app in front and slim in back end but when hit the api url in browser its not working but in postman its working fine thanks!

**Note**

> i have followed every related posts out there in   stack overflow but
>   still i did not get any solution

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://school_erp_api.dev/login' from 
origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Comment: *i have followed every related posts* Can you explain in the answer?

Comment: yes i have followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479150/access-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access and others related also

Comment: You can use by setting Proxy for local development or there is an extension from Chrome.

Comment: can you tell me the name of the extenstion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, your backend needs to respond with an Allow-Origin header so that your preflight (OPTIONS request) passes and the server allows CORS. So, your backend should send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <domain>, ... | *`

For a way to implement this using slim, have a look [here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html)